# Unable to create a constant value of type 'LookupObject'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

How can I solve this problem ?

I need to do this check between the database and a list of in-memory objects

```cs
var contactIds = db.AGN_RestrictionContact_Involvement_PositionLinked
        .Where(x => x.Id_AGN_Contato == formModel.ContactId);

var positionRemove = contactIds.Where(x => !formModel.PositionsInvolvement
        .Any(l => l.Id == x.Id_PRO_PosicaoEnvolvido)).ToList();

foreach (var position in positionRemove)
{
    db.AGN_RestrictionContact_Involvement_PositionLinked.Remove(position);
}
```

Comment: Use `Contains` instead of `Any`. `!formModel.PositionsInvolvement.Select(i => i.Id).Contains(x.Id_PRO_PosicaoEnvolvido)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution didn't work :/
I keep getting the same error ...

Comment: Add call stack to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reach a simple resolution where I add to the end of this query =>

```
var contactIds = db.AGN_RestrictionContact_Involvement_PositionLinked
        .Where(x => x.Id_AGN_Contato == formModel.ContactId).ToList();
```

the `ToList()`

Where the query will also stay in memory so as not to cause problems in my viewModel's 'PositionsInvolvement' property